# How to read a variable stored in a json file from helm yaml template

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I have a json file which have a variable called imageTag stored. I want to use that imageTag variable in one of my helm templates. something like

image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/nginx/nginx:{{imageTag}}

json file:
{
"imageTag": "1.15.5-alpine"
}

This json file is not specific to one particular helm, I want to use it for multiple clusters. So am not sure if I can use values.yaml here since it is specific to that particular cluster? I am still a rookie in AKS, so please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that are useful to you here:

1. Any valid JSON is also valid YAML
2. You can use the `helm install -f` option to supply additional YAML (or JSON) files, which get combined with the chart's `values.yaml` file

So if your chart says

```yaml
image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/nginx/nginx:{{ .Values.imageTag }}
```

and your `env.json` file includes

```json
{"imageTag":"1.15.5-alpine"}
```

and you run

```bash
helm install my-chart . -f env.json
```

then both the chart's `values.yaml` file and the `env.json` will get read, and you'll have access to the values from both.

There are more complex options possible by [reading the file from inside the chart](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/), but if you can use the `helm install -f` option it will be much more straightforward.  I'd only go for a `.Files.Get` based approach if you don't have much control over either the JSON file layout and you're afraid of the it unintentionally introducing values that conflict with your chart's settings.